# datetime-local does not show value

Tags: jquery, datetime

I have this input field

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="event_start_date" id="event_start_date" class="form-control onlydatepicker" placeholder="Event start date">
```

I select the date and time and I save it in a database as "2023-09-13T18:14" .

I get the value from the database and save it in a variable using ajax.
I use the below code to set it

```
var g_start = moment(event.start).format();
console.log(g_start);
$('#edit_event_start_date').attr('value', g_start);
```

I see that the value is assigned correctly to datetime-local, but I do not see it. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Use `.val(g_start)` rather than `.attr('value', g_start)`

Comment: I tried with val(g_start) but I do not see it on the field

Comment: You don't see dynamic value changes in the DOM inspector. The value attribute in the DOM is used as the initial default value, it's not the current value when the user interact with the element.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html

Comment: That you see in the DOM is the selected value from the database. I have no default value on the input datetime-local

Comment: What is the real problem? If you want to set the current value of the input, you use `.val()`. This isn't supposed to show up in the inspector.

Comment: I used .val() function but I do not see the selected value on the datetime field

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Typo: `$('#edit_event_start_date')` should be `$('#event_start_date')` -- there's no `edit` in the ID.

Comment: When I fix that it works: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/kf8dqxL1/1/

Comment: OK I Found my issue. In the database I have 2023-09-04T19:00 . I use moment to parse the unix timestamp I get back like 
var g_start = moment(event.start).utc().format();
console.log(g_start);
The output is "2023-09-06T18:14:00Z" and Z in the end prevent to see the value in the datetime field

Comment: I fix it like this and worked
var g_start = moment(event.start, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format().replace('Z', '');
$('#edit_event_start_date').val(g_start);